# Formula for COUNTIFS excluding another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm trying but failing to work out a formula in Excel 2007.  I have an large area of data that isn't in a table format.  The main columns I care about are: chapter title (text), number of tasks (text), percentage complete for each task (numeric).

Underneath the data there is a summary table where we count the overall number of tasks and the number of tasks at each percentage level.  I have been asked to create a summary to exclude a particular chapter which I can do from the main summary with =COUNTIFS(range,<>chapter1).  I also need to exclude this chapter at each percentage point (eg. count of tasks at 10% complete except those for chapter 1).  This is where I come unstuck.

I'd really appreciate some assistance.  I've never really needed to use formulas before and I'm struggling with these!

Comment: Hi. Perhaps you could post a very small dataset together with your expected result?

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty broad, but essentially I think I understand what you're trying to accomplish. Let's take an example spreadsheet like this -

```
Title   Tasks   Percent Done
ch1     task1       75%
ch1     task2       50%
ch2     task3       25%
ch2     task4       75%
ch3     task5       50%
ch3     task6       25%
```

From what I gather, you want a summary of task completion excluding a given chapter.

So if you want to count how many tasks exist for a chapter you'd use -

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A7,"<>ch1")
```

Now you know there are 4 tasks that aren't for "ch1".

Now, how many of those tasks are greater than 25% done?

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A7,"<>ch1",C2:C7,">.25")
```

More than 50%?

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A7,"<>ch1",C2:C7,">.5")
```

How about excluding chapter 3, how many tasks are at least 75% done?

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A7,"<>ch3",C2:C7,">=.75")
```